# what is the meaning of dashed red line in memory_profiler plot

Tags: python-2.7, memory-profiling

What does the dotted red-line convey here while plotting memory consumption graph with memory_profiler (python tool)?

Figure: www.goo.gl/LwgmeB

I get this dotted line even with one function.
Tool Link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler

Comment: related: https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler/issues/308

Answer (score 2):

It points to the peak in memory usage, both in terms of amount of memory (y axis) and time (x axis). This is perhaps best seen in this image [image: memory profiler memory plot]

Comment: could be nice to add this explanation to the usage page: https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler/issues/308 (or say in the docs red line I can't find the word red there). Btw, thanks for the great lib!